# how to exclude some disabled links from styling?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have some anchor links in my application which when disabled should look gray so I applied the following code in css file:-

```
a[disabled] 
 { 
    color: Grey !important; 
    text-decoration: none !important; 
 }
```

This seem to work fine but I want to exclude 1 link from taking this style when disabled. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give me the condition you want to exclude..?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
a[disabled]:not(your selector) 
 { 
    color: Grey !important; 
    text-decoration: none !important; 
 }
```

e.g.

```
a[disabled]:not(:nth-of-type(2)) 
 { 
    color: Grey !important; 
    text-decoration: none !important; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks your selector is wrong. It has to be

```
a[disabled=disabled]{
    color: Grey !important; 
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xyh5j4mr/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160376/change-the-appearance-of-a-disabled-link)

Comment: The link to exclude is asp:hyerlink. Do I have to mention its Id at the "your selector" here? Link to exclude code-"                                                <asp:HyperLink   ID="lnkTermsFields" runat="server" Text="Add" NavigateUrl="javascript:void(0);" /> and there are more hyperlinks like that. They display like buttons so have to be excluded.